# React Native a component being only rendered once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-component

I'm using both librarys
import SwipeCards from 'react-native-swipe-cards';
and
import AutoTypingText from 'react-native-auto-typing-text';

In each card I have I use AutoTypingText, The problem is that it uses the same text in all of them, The only thing that does change is this.props.Nickname

**Which is not part of the text prop for AutoTypingText**

Child Card Component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>{this.props.Nickname}</Text>
            <AutoTypingText
                text={"\nAge: " + this.props.Age + "\n"
                    + "City: " + this.props.City + "\n"
                    + "Recent Login: " + this.props.RecentActivity + "\n"
                    + "Points: " + this.props.Points + "\n"
                    + "About: \"" + this.props.About + "\"\n"
                }
                charMovingTime={0}
                style={textStyle}
                delay={0}
                onComplete={() => {
                    console.log('done');
                    console.log(this.state)
                }}
            />

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                <Button style={styles.buttonStyle} textStyle={styles.buttonText}>
                    Exploit !
                </Button>
                <Button style={styles.buttonStyle} textStyle={styles.buttonText}>
                    Spare
                </Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
    }
}
```

Parent Cards List

```
const Cards = [
{
    Nickname: "S4nr0",
    Age: 25,
    City: "New-York",
    RecentActivity: "17/07/2016 14:11PM",
    About: "I <3 Kittenz",
    Points: 1337
},
{
    Nickname: "Sr00lik",
    Age: 23,
    City: "New-York",
    RecentActivity: "17/07/2016 14:11PM",
    About: "If Internet explorer is brave\nenough to ask you to be your\n default browser, you're brave \nenough to ask that girl out",
    Points: 1337
},
{
    Nickname: "Bomba",
    Age: 24,
    City: "New-York",
    RecentActivity: "17/07/2016 14:11PM",
    About: "I'm Awesome !",
    Points: 1337
}
];

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
    return {
      cards: Cards
    }
  },
render() {
    return (
      <SwipeCards
        cards={this.state.cards}
        renderCard={(cardData) => <Card {...cardData} />}
      />
    )
    }
})
```

To clarify: It's as if AutoTypingText is like a singleton (I know it's not),
Because the results of it are the same in all of the cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the proper answer but in react native, usually helps providing a key attribute to elements that repeat to make sure the "virtual DOM" detects changes.

So you could do something like:

```
<AutoTypingText
            key={this.props. Nickname}
            text={"\nAge: " + this.props.Age + "\n"
                + "City: " + this.props.City + "\n"
                + "Recent Login: " + this.props.RecentActivity + "\n"
                + "Points: " + this.props.Points + "\n"
                + "About: \"" + this.props.About + "\"\n"
            }
            ...
```

Give it a try ; )